# interpreting R plot of 100 t-confidence intervals on same graph.

Tags: r, confidence-interval, estimation, t-test, inference

I have drawn 100 sample of size 10 from standard normal distribution using r . after that for each repetition the 95% t-confidence intervals have been plotted on the same graph paper and those intervals that don't cover the empiracal population mean '0' have been marked  in 'red'. But what's the interpretation of this kind of graphs ? [image]

Comment: How many 'red bars' would you expect if you compute a 95% confidence interval?

Comment: less than 5 .. ! as the probability of 'red bans' is theoretically  0.05 .

Comment: my question is , here we already know the mean beforehand. then why are we doing this ..?